# Can an immigrant create a new business while their green card is pending?

Tags: united-states, business, immigration, incorporation

My fiance is hoping to form a new business in the United States, but she is wondering if she can create a new business (example, LLC) while her green card is pending?

Comment: Does she have an EAD?

Comment: @phoog I believe she does. Does it matter with or without one?

Comment: Does she want to be an employee of this business, or work for it in any way?  If she doesn't have employment authorization, she can't do those.

Comment: @Nate Eldredge She is going to own and run this business.

Comment: @JeremyTrpka running the business is work, which requires an EAD.  If she has an EAD as you suspect, she should be fine.  If her green card application is refused, however, she'll need to leave the country and probably hire someone local to run her business.

Comment: @ohwilleke Not sure how the question is similar to that question considering my fiance is currently living in the US and wants to form a company within the US as well. Though she does have an F-1 status as well, but the question states about a possible pending of a green card.

Comment: @JeremyTrpka has she applied for adjustment of status, or is your question about whether she will be allowed to form a business after a future application for adjustment of status?

Comment: @phoog We just want to know if she is allowed to form a business during the adjustment.

Comment: You might want to ask on [Expatriates.SE].  My understanding is that she can form the business whenever, but she can't actually work at it unless she's authorized to work.  Some time *after* she applies for AoS, she'll receive that authorization in the form of an EAD.  It seems to take quite a few months; I have a friend who recently received his after maybe six months, although I do not remember exactly how long it was.

Comment: @phoog I might go ahead and use some of your comment as the answer.

Comment: @JeremyTrpka please do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"My understanding is that she can form the business whenever, but she can't actually work at it unless she's authorized to work. Some time after she applies for AoS, she'll receive that authorization in the form of an EAD." - phoog

Comment: Note that she would only receive an EAD if she applied for an EAD (which she can do, for free, as an AOS applicant, but she would still need to specifically apply for it)